# count new elements in vector list

Tags: r, lapply

I want to count new elements that weren't present in previous years. In the example

**Sample data:**

```
var1 <- list('2003' = 1:3, '2004' = c(4:3), '2005' = c(6,4,1), '2006' = 1:4 )
```

I would like to get the output

```
newcount <- list('2003' = 0, '2004' = 1, '2005' = 1, '2006' = 0)
```

**Unsuccessful code:**

```
newcount <- mapply(setdiff, var1, seq_along(var1), function(i) 
            {if (i > 1) {Reduce(union, var1[i-1], accumulate=T)}}, length)
```

Comment: Please study the terminology. You have a list of vectors, not data frames.

Comment: `diff( sapply( Reduce(union, var1, accumulate = TRUE) ,length))` 
#[1] 1 1 0

Comment: @DWin, this would be my chosen solution if you had made it an answer rather than a comment. Very neat, very readable!

Comment: James' solution was where I got the idea. I just trimmed his a bit. Didn't seem right to add it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Almost there, but its better to use vector indexing to work with the offset and add the always-known initial element afterwards:

```
lapply(c(list(`2003`=integer(0)),
       mapply(setdiff,var1[-1], 
              Reduce(union,var1,accumulate=TRUE)[-length(var1)])),length)
$`2003`
[1] 0

$`2004`
[1] 1

$`2005`
[1] 1

$`2006`
[1] 0
```

Comment: Where you going for the maximum number of function calls in a single line with that one? ;-) (Seriously though, that is massive overkill.)

Comment: Well, 80 characters is so passé ;)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that `var1` is sorted according to year, and that for 2003 you'd like `3` instead of `1`, you could try

```
newcount <- lapply(seq_along(var1),function(x){
  prev<-unlist(var1[seq_len(x-1)])
# Improvement suggested by plannapus
  sum(!var1[[x]]%in%prev) # length(which(!var1[[x]]%in%prev))
})

names(newcount)<-names(var1)

newcount
# $`2003`
# [1] 3

# $`2004`
# [1] 1

# $`2005`
# [1] 1

# $`2006`
# [1] 0
```

OK, if you're absolutely sure that 2003 should be 0 (which I see as an exception to your logic), then you could do the following:

```
newcount <- c(0, lapply(seq_along(var1)[-1],function(x){
  prev<-unlist(var1[seq_len(x-1)])
  sum(!var1[[x]]%in%prev)
}))
```

Comment: @plannapus, Good suggestion. Changed above.

Comment: Also, there are no previous years for 2003 so it should be 0 if we are counting number of things found in previous years?

Comment: @GavinSimpson, thanks for the comment. I think the OP wanted the number of elements in year i that were not present in any previous year. So although I can understand having 0 for 2003, it seems to be an exception to the rule. It'd be an easy change, but a "hard code".

Comment: Yeah, just work over `2:length(var1)` and hard code the 0. The OP's expected output is pretty clear